# JPA Criteria Query Builder: Get last Entry

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently building a complex query with JPA CriteriaBuilder.
In this query i join a little databases. Now i need only the last Entry of a joined Table. But i don't know where i must applicate that in the query.

Here is a dummy JPA query:

```
private CriteriaQuery<Class2> getClass2Function {
    CriteriaQuery<RootClass> cq = cb.createQuery(RootClass.class);
    Root<RootClass> root = cq.from(RootClass.class);
    Join<RootClass, Class2> class2 = root.join(RootClass_.class2Id);
    ListJoin<Class2, Class3> class3 = class2.join(Class2_.listOfClass3);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.isNull(class3.get(SomeModel_.dtDl)));
    predicates.add(cb.isNull(class2.get(SomeModel_.dtDl)));
    predicates.add(cb.isNull(root.get(SomeModel_.dtDl)));

    return cq.select(class2).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))
              .orderBy(cb.asc(class2.get(Class2_.id)));
}
```

Now i need only the last entry of the `ListJoin class3`, how can i do this?

Greetings

Comment: what is "last entry"? last element of a List field? Provide the entity classes

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes last element of a List<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.
I needed to add the following code:

```
Subquery<Long> sq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Class3> root = sq.from(Class3.class);
sq.select(cb.max(root.get(Class3_.id)));
predicates.add(cb.equal(class3.get(Class3_.id), sq));
```

I hope i could help someone.

Comment: will that work if objects are placed in the List in a different order to their "id"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you care about the order of elements in a list, you need the `@OrderColumn` annotation. Depending on any other mechanism for maintaining list order is dependent on the database and persistence provider and, in the general case, unreliable.

Assuming you already have that, you should be able to combine `class3.order()` with `cb.size(class3)` in a predicate.