# Hibernate one-to-many association getting latest entry using criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a relation similar to

```
Person (1) ----> Order (N)
```

Essentially one-to-many relation between Person and Order tables.

I want to define a QueryCriteria so that when I load Person entity I only load a single Order or the most recent order .

How do I do that?

I have been trying

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = _entityManagerProvider.get().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PersonEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(PersonEntity.class);
    Root<PersonEntity> root = cq.from(PersonEntity.class);
    ListJoin<PersonEntity, OrderEntity> listJoin = root.joinList("orderEntityList");


    Subquery<Long> sq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<OrderEntity> orderRoot = sq.from(OrderEntity.class);
    sq.select(cb.max(orderRoot.get("id")));


    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.equal(listJoin.get("id"), sq));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("personId"), personId));

    cq.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

    final List<PersonEntity> entityList = _entityManagerProvider.get().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

I am getting entityList as empty. However in backend i do have two order entry for given person and I was hoping to get recent order entry.

---- Edit ----

So I figured the issue is around
sq.select(cb.max(orderRoot.get("id")));

Its returning the max Id from order table for obvious reason. What I need is Id for order with max create date , something like

```
sq.select(orderRoot.get("id")).where(cb.max(orderRoot.get("createDate"))
```

How do I get above implementation?

Comment: I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752382/jpa-criteria-query-builder-get-last-entry .. seems i am doing similar. but i am not getting the correct results.

Comment: What you are doing is, you have a `Person` entity, with relationship to bunch of `Orders` (assume the field name `orders`), and in some query you want to retrieve only some of the orders. I always have an impression of such approach is going to be unreliable as 1) I doubt if Hibernate is going to be smart enough to know your list is only partially retrieved and it do correct subsequent handling, and 2) if in your session you have previously retrieved that person with all orders retrieved, Hibernate will simply return you the same instance

Comment: So essentially what I need is person data with its latest order.. For now i am getting the list and using order by in entity relation . But I was hoping to handle this using criteria and get only the latest record from order table..
Above works in a sense that I always get the max id from order, what I need is Id for order with max created date for the given person relation

Comment: imho the "proper way" is not to "retrieve most recent order in `orders`", but have a query to return you a Person and an Order, and let you do the subsequent handling; or, you should have a separate readonly one-to-one relationship in `Person` to `Order`, like `latestOrder`, and you could use things like `@Subselect` (or some other similar facilities?) to map this relationship to that "select max" query

Comment: (tbh I haven't tried those trick relationship mapping myself... you may need to do some extra study if you want to take the 2nd method )

Comment: So one way I am handling this is loading the entity with person -> orders where in orders list is sorted based on created date and I pick the first record. That works.. However, I was wondering if this is something that can be done using criteria